# higher dimensional Pauli matrices?

Tags: matrices

I'm trying to find $3 \times 3$ matrices with some similarity to Pauli matrices.
I have some candidates, but they are not perfect. I'm not sure if perfect versions exist, and that is my question.

Recall for [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices) $p_k$:
$\{p_i,p_j\} = p_ip_j + p_jp_i = 2 \delta_{ij}$

I'm looking for matrices that satisfy:
$\{a_i,a_j,a_k\} = 3! \delta_{ijk}$
where $\{A,B,C\}$ is the sum over all permutations of three symbols:
$\{A,B,C\} = ABC + BCA + CAB + ACB + CBA + BAC$

My candidate matrices are:

$a_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}$
$a_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & a\\
b & 0 & 0\\
0 & c & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}$
$a_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & a & 0\\
0 & 0 & b\\
c & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}$
$a_4 = \begin{bmatrix}
a & 0 & 0\\
0 & b & 0\\
0 & 0 & c\\
\end{bmatrix}$

where $a,b,c$ are the three third roots of unity (and have the property $a + b + c = 0$).
And of course, unlike Pauli matrices, the eigenvalues of these matrices are not real (they are $a,b,c$), which is expected since they are permutation matrices with $a^3 = I$.

Now, they have the desired property of:

$\{a_1,a_1,a_1\} = 3\\
\{a_1,a_1,a_2\} = 0\\
\{a_1,a_2,a_3\} = 0\\
\{a_1,a_3,a_4\} = 0\\ \cdots$

However: 
$\{a_2,a_3,a_4\} = -3I$

So my question is, are there a set of 4 matrices that satisfy
$\{a_i,a_j,a_k\} = 3! \delta_{ijk}$

We have 3 such matrices $a_1,a_2,a_3$, but do there exist 4?
I'm 90% sure the answer is no, but I'd like to be 100%.

And we can extend the problem to higher dimensions:
For example, the $d = 4$ case. Define:
$\{A,B,C,D\}$ as the sum over all permutations of four symbols.
How many matrices can we find that satisfy:
$\{a_i,a_j,a_k,a_l\} = 4! \delta_{ijkl}$
It suspect it might be 3 for all higher d.

Now, where did this problem come from? Consider:

$M_1 = u*a_1 + v*a_2 + w*a_3$ such that $M_1^3 = (u^3 + v^3 + w^3)I$

And $M_2 = u*a_1 + v*a_2 + x*a_3 + y*a_4$ such that $M_2^3 = (u^3 + v^3 + x^3 + y^3)I$

And their determinants:

$\det(M_1) = u^3 + v^3 + w^3\\
\det(M_2) = u^3 + v^3 + x^3 + y^3 -3vxy$

So an alternative definition of the problem, do there exist matrices, not equal to the identity matrix, $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ such that $\det(M_2)$ doesn't have the cross term? Similarly for higher $d$, where the determinant gets even messier! eg: $d = 4, M = u*b_1 + v*b_2 + x*b_3 + y*b_4$ and $\det(M) = u^4 + v^4 + x^4 + y^4 + mess$

Answer (score 2):

Not a full answer but a suggestion that is a bit too long to fit into a comment.

The most important property about Pauli matrices is not the one you give but the following
$$ p_ip_j=\sum_k\varepsilon_{ijk}\;p_k$$
where $\varepsilon_{ijk}=\pm1$ if $(i,j,k)$ is a permutation of $(1,2,3)$. The sign $\pm1$ is the signature of the permutation. In all other cases, $\varepsilon_{ijk}=0$. It is easy to check that the property $\{p_i,p_j\}=2\delta_{ij}$ is a direct consequence of this more fundamental property.

So you should try to look for permutation matrices satisfying 
$$ q_iq_jq_k=\varepsilon_{ijk\ell}q_\ell$$
and they will immediately verify $\{q_i,q_j,q_k\}=6\delta_{ijk}$.

Comment: that makes sense. Though you are missing a $\delta_{ijk}I$ term. I find the {a,b,c} anticommutator version easier to verify in mathematica though.

Comment: OK. Your equation implies: $q_1q_2q_3 = q_4$ 
So use my $a_1, a_2, a_3$ from above, and try this candidate as the fourth matrix: $a_5 = a_1a_2a_3$
Then set $X = u*a_1 + v*a2 + x*a3 + y*a5$ and take the determinant:
$$Det(X) = u^3 + v^3 + x^3 + y^3 -3uvy$$
So we still have the cross term.

Answer (score 0):

Pauli matrices are essentially 4-dimensional split-complex numbers. Split-complex numbers can be only $2^n$-dimensional.

Particularly, the 8-dimensional split-complex space can be represented with real matrices as:

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right);\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right);\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right);\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right);$
$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right);\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right);\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right);\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right).$

Alternatively, you can take a look at [Triplex numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4733180/2513), but they are not the same thing.

Comment: My original post was from long ago. I now consider the cross-term to be desirable, not something to be eliminated. And I have a set of 8 3x3 matrices, plus the identity matrix, that satisfy my required properties. This comment box is too small to provide them however.

Comment: @Garry you definitely would be able to put them in comments, but I just provided info about higher-dimensional analog of Pauli matrices.

Comment: OK. Here they are then: $$ T1 = \begin{bmatrix}

Comment: @Garry something is wrong with your post. Do not press enter when writing comments.

Comment: Yeah, I am struggling with the interface!

Comment: @You can build formula offline and the copy-paste it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the original post I now think the cross terms are desirable, and not something to be eliminated. Consequently, I have settled on the below set of matrices (along with the identity matrix):
$$
T_1 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
T_2 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & w^2 \\
w & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
T_3 =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & w & 0 \\
0 & 0 & w^2 
\end{bmatrix}
T_4 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & w \\
w^2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
And the second set are:
$$
\tau_1 = T_2 T_3 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & w \\
w & 0 & 0 \\
0 & w & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
\tau_2 = T_3 T_1 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & w \\
w^2 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
\tau_3 = T_1 T_2 =
\begin{bmatrix}
w & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & w^2 
\end{bmatrix}
\tau_4 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & w^2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & w \\
1 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
with the properties:
$$r = p_1 T_1 + p_2 T_2 + p_3 T_3 + p_4 T_4$$ and $$r^3 = J_3(p_1, p_2, p_3) + p_4^3$$
And the second set have similar properties:
$$s = q_1 \tau_1 + q_2 \tau_2 + q_3 \tau_3 + q_4 \tau_4$$ and $$s^3 = J_3(q_1, q_2, q_3) + q_4^3$$
where $$J_3(a,b,c) = a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - 3 a b c$$ is the determinant of a 3x3 circulant matrix.
And $w$ is the principle third root of unity with the standard property $w^3 = +1$. The 3x3 circulant matrix is given by $$
C = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c \\
c & a & b \\
b & c & a 
\end{bmatrix}
$$